# What is the difference between an untaggedImage & deletedImage in the docker source?

Tags: docker, go

The docker source defines a struct to hold deleted images when running `docker image prune` or `docker system prune`:

```
type ImageDeleteResponseItem struct {

    // The image ID of an image that was deleted
    Deleted string `json:"Deleted,omitempty"`

    // The image ID of an image that was untagged
    Untagged string `json:"Untagged,omitempty"`
}
```

([source code link](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/api/types/image_delete_response_item.go))

Looking at the comments I don't get the difference between the two. Aren't all untagged images also deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary that untagging deletes an image. If you have an image tagged with more than one tag. It'll delete the tag and image will be there with the other tag.

`docker rmi first-tag` will remove the `first-tag` but will still persist the image with `second-tag`. It would have been disastrous if it deleted the whole image whenever we tried to remove the tag.

You can see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/703344/how-to-remove-an-image-tag-in-docker-without-removing-the-image-itself) for more.

Comment: So this means that removing a tag has no effect on the space reclaimed during `docker system prune`. We only reclaim space when the image itself is removed. Is this true?

Comment: yes that's true. we reclaim space only when image itself is removed. Also as docker image is made up of layers so its not necessary that an image of 1.5 GB on deletion vacates 1.5GB space.